# How do I create a table-like layout with fluid positioning? [Image inside]

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning, fluid-layout

**Here's the layout im looking for:**

[image: The layout im looking for]
[image: Expanded]
[image: Tighter]

Right now, all my boxes have a right and bottom margin, and I have to remove the right margin on every 3rd element to not make it overflow the wrapper and fall down to the next line.

If I resize the wrapper, I have to manually calibrate the margins to position the boxes, which feels hacky at best.

What I would hope to do is have an HTML markup that's not more complicated than this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Which produces the layout seen above; expanding margins until there's room for another box on the same row, and collapsing rows if it's too tight. Is it possible using nothing but CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say the margin between the boxes is 20px. I suggest to set the margin to the bottom and left side of the boxes. Set the width of the wrapper so it fits all the boxes including their margins(in this case 360px wide). Then set the margin-left of the wrapper to -20px.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tYHuh/)

```
#wrapper {
    width: 360px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Even though it's not exactly what I was looking for, it's a vast improvement over my current method. Thanks!